# How do I print the content of a file?

Tags: c++, file

How can I print the contents of a file, the name of which is specified via my program's command line?

I do not know how to give the name of file by command line and how to work with it.

For ex this is does not work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char s[20];
    cin >> s;
    f=fopen_s(s,"rt");
    std::cout << f;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

error C2660

Comment: Is that your entire program? Are there any `#include` directives? The message "error C2660" is compiler-specific; what is the full error message?

Comment: That's all so blatantly wrong. Have a look at [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) first please. `fopen()` isnt't what you want in c++.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <iostream>
     #include <fstream>
     int main(int argc , char *argv[])
     {
        if(argc < 2) 
       {
        std::cout << " Wrong usage " << std::endl;
        exit(0);
       }
      std::string file_name = argv[1]; 
      std::ifstream fs;
      fs.open(file_name.c_str());
      std::cout << file_name << std::endl;
      std::string line ;
      while(fs >> line)
      {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
      }
      return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use << operator with char[]

Solution : You can use std::string

```
std::string s;
```

2. Use the string's c_str() value as name in fopen_s(name, "rt")

Solution : You need to put the file in the same directory as the executable

```
f = fopen_s(s.c_str(), "rt");
```

3. You cannot cout << FILE *f

Solution : read file content line by line as you print each line

```
char* line; //used to receive data for each line
int length; //used to represent how many characters have received
while ((getline(&line, &length, f) != -1) {
    print("%s", line);
}
```